# What's the name of this part of combustion chamber and what is it for?

Tags: jet-engine, feature-identification, combustion

There are two "excrescences" Near the end of diffuser of some combustion chambers. e.g. CFM56 and F101
What's the name of this part of combustion chamber and what is it for?

[image]

Comment: I don't known if it has a particular name, this is just the rear end of the diffuser, but it seems for maintaining the flow continuity as long as possible, [orienting air](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o2tD.png) onto the swirl nozzles and limiting air entering the combustor through the inner liner cooling and dilution holes.

Answer (score 1):

On depictions of the CFM56 combustion chamber, that's part of the cross-section depiction of the diffuser.